# Extend LVM partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm

I need to extend existing LVM mounted to /opt. I've created new volume sdb2 and mounted it to /opt, but disk space in df -h output still the same. What esle should I do?

lsblk output:

```
└─sda3                            8:3    0   399G  0 part
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv       253:0    0    20G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0            253:1    0   579G  0 lvm  /opt
sdb                               8:16   0   350G  0 disk
├─sdb1                            8:17   0   200G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0            253:1    0   579G  0 lvm  /opt
└─sdb2                            8:18   0   150G  0 part
  └─ubuntu----vg--lv----0-lvol0 253:2    0 136.7G  0 lvm  /opt
```

Comment: You mounted a new partition over the original? That's incorrect. Also, are you trying to add a partition on the same disk to the volume group? You may as well grow sdb1, the volume group and the volume, in that order.

Comment: @Halfgaar, could you please write example how to do it? I am totally new to this

Comment: There are plenty of articles out there that describe it. But if you really are totally new, beware of what you're doing. A wrong move and you may have deleted your data.